# Can Ruby recognise different spellings of the same word?

Tags: ruby

When getting user input, is there a way to recognise `"gr*y"` (where the `*` character doesn't matter) other than writing each spelling like `"grey"` and `"gray"` in my code?

Comment: You can investigate using a [Soundex library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to achieve deducing words that 'sound like' what the intended word is even if badly misspelled. There are numerous FLOS libraries for Soundex including for Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a regular expression. Though, you *probably* wouldn't want to match any character -- it might work in this particular instance, but could completely change the meaning of other words.

For example, `/gr(a|e)y/` would match both "gray" and "grey".

If you did want to match *any* single character, you could use a range, like `/gr[a-zA-Z]y/`.

Here's a working example on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/JhkRixOBSo).

There's also probably a gem which wraps up all of these common spellings. I'd suggest searching on rubygems.org and ruby-toolbox.com.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is called `fuzzy match` or `fuzzy search`.

I've found 3 libraries, which provide such a functionality:

- https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match
- https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match
- https://github.com/flori/amatch

You can look through the docs of each of them and decide, which is more preferable for you case. I just show the example of `amatch`:

```
require 'amatch'
include Amatch

m = Levenshtein.new("grey")
m.match('gray') # 1
m.match('pray') # 2
```

It calculates the Levenshtein distance between two words: the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other. Thus, in order to count `gray` and `grey` words as the same, you need to set allowable distance as `1`.